# Understanding a flatten function

Tags: javascript, image, function, flatten

What does this  function do? Specifically, what is the tag referring to?

```
function flattenImages(images, tags) {
    var flattened = [];
    for (const list of Object.values(images)) {
        for (const element of list) {
            flattened.push(Object.assign({image:element}, tags))
        }
    }
    return flattened
}
```

Comment: "*what is the tag referring to?*" what you pass as an argument. There is no way to know without seeing how this is called.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.